# Is GolangLibs officially supported by Golang/Google?

Tags: go

Is GolangLibs (https://golanglibs.com/) officially supported by Golang/Google?

I didn't find anything on their website.

Comment: There is nothing on that page to indicate that it has any association with Google. If you want an authoritative answer, ask on one of the Go mailing lists. This seems off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Unless Google refers to itself as "I", then it's obviously not from Google, since the front page says "Once a week I send out a list..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's just a site for searching golang packages based on github trends and stars.